# moving a field value up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am trying to move a field from subdocument up in "all" documents. Any help is appreciated.

The schema looks something like this. It is not necessary that "all" documents will have "tryouts" subdocuments but need the update done for whichever is available. mongo or ruby code help is very much appreciated.

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("37035cs978952"),
 "tryouts": {
          "dat": "2011-09-09T15: 52: 26+01: 00",
          "a": "a",
          "b": "c",

         }
 }
```

All I need to do is move "dat" value up, to have something like this;

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("37035cs978952"),
 "dat": "2011-09-09T15: 52: 26+01: 00"
 "tryouts": {
          "a": "a",
          "b": "c",

         }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
 db.sample4.find().forEach(function(doc){var value = doc.tryouts.dat;db.sample4.update(doc,{$set:{dat:value}});});
 db.sample4.update({},{$unset:{"tryouts.dat":1}},true);
```